# Get accessToken in Identity Server ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer with an ASP.NET Core MVC applications.

In IdentityServer my client defined like this:

```
new Client
    {
        ClientId = "admin.client",
        ClientName = "Admin Application",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                        },
        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:45876/signin-oidc" },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:45876/signout-callback-oidc" },
        AllowedCorsOrigins = new[] { "http://localhost:45876/" },
        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                        },
        AllowOfflineAccess = true
}
```

And client register like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect(
                "oidc",
                options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001/";
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;


                        options.ClientId = "admin.client";
                        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                        options.Scope.Add("openid");
                        options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    });
```

My problem is when I want to get accessToken that is null.

I'm trying to get it with this code:

```
 var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
 string accessToken = User.FindFirst("access_token")?.Value;
```

Both of them return null.

Where is my problem?

Comment: You have no problems with login? The user is authenticated?

Comment: Yes, The use is authenticated and I can get User.Claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are config the client application to use the `Hybrid flow` to interact with IdentityServer :

```
 options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
```

But the client config is only allowed to use `Implicit flow` :

```
 AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
```

That will threw `invalid grant type` error during the authentication request .

The second problem is that you didn't config the `ApiResource` :

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
}
```

The client is also not request the permission to access api resource , although you can make your client application authenticate user with identity server , it will return back `ID token` , not `Access token` :

- `ID token` contains at a bare minimum an identifier for the user (called the sub aka subject claim) and information about how and when the user authenticated
- `Access token` allows access to an API resource , contain information about the client and the user (if present).

Since you are using web application(mvc as client app) . A better choice to to use `hybrid flow` , which enables both API access and user authentication. [Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess) is code sample .